# After changing input value, JS still shows old value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to change the value of an input field after the user clicks on a button. It changes the value to `false`, but it doesn't seem like it actually "refreshes" when calling the `.val()` again.

Here's a JS Fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/hguom7x8/

As you can see, the alert shows that the value is `true`, and then it shows that it's `false`, but then it doesn't show that it's `true` any time after that anymore.

```js
$("#filter_assessment_list").click(function(){
  upcoming_assessments = $("#upcoming_assessments").val()
  alert(upcoming_assessments)
  if(upcoming_assessments){
    $("#upcoming_assessments").val(false)
  }
  else{
    $("#upcoming_assessments").val(true)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary text-white" id="filter_assessment_list" href="javascript:;">
        Show only upcoming assessments
</a>

<input type="hidden" name="upcoming_assessments" id="upcoming_assessments" value="true">
```

Comment: strings are truthy... you do not have a boolean. `console.log(typeof upcoming_assessments)`

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks @epascarello. Didn't catch that but now we're rocking and rolling!